# How to create a script that launches a random video file from the folder

Tags: script, powershell, shell-script

So, this is a weird problem.

But basically, my nephew likes watching cartoons on my computer sometimes. And that worked well. OVer time, his cartoon folder grew up.

Here's the problem: he wants to watch random episodes. BUT, my initial solution - which was to add all episodes to a playlist and then just turn on shuffle in the video player wasn't good enough, because then "he knows which ones he can expect because he can see the possible outcomes"...

So, the current solution is that he simply enters the folder, holds the DOWN key for a few seconds and intercepts it with a ENTER press. That worked ok for him, until he ended up watching the same one for a week straight. And because "i make computery stuff" he asked me to make him one episode/file which he can click on, and play just one random episode.

I'm open to any powershell / whichever script solution for Windows. The files aren't executable, so they just need to open with the default viewing program (windows media player for example)

Can you please help me out and/or give me a hint? I just need something that launches a random file from a folder, for a little kid :)

Comment: Which video player do you use normally?

Comment: "because he can see the possible outcomes" - So why not just turn the playlist view off? If your player doesn't support this then use one that does.

Comment: Thanks for helping out by suggesting i argue or reason with a child. I actually understood what he meant, and he just wanted to be pseudo-surprised by the choice every time he launched it. 

And the accepted solution did the trick. But hey - maybe I should've just switched the video player and solved it that way. Hooray for that line of though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i resolved the issue using the following .BAT file.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD /D %~dp0
Set Count=0
For /F "tokens=*" %%f In ('Dir /A-D /B *.flv *.mp4') Do (Set /A Count=!Count+1)
Set /A Skip=%Random%%%%Count%
If %Skip%==0 (Set Skip=) Else (Set Skip=skip=%Skip%)
Set RandomFile=
For /F "%Skip% tokens=*" %%f In ('Dir /A-D /B *.flv *.mp4') Do (If "!RandomFile!"=="" SetRandomFile=%%f)
Start "" "%RandomFile%"
EndLocal
```

Thanks for the interest :)